# Unable to Load Application. Incompatible library version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting strange error when running puma server. Previously it was working fine when I visit the normal page and the error only occured when I try to register a user. Now when starting the puma server it says

> Unable to load application: LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/bed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/lib/bcrypt_ext.so

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bcrypt'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'rspec-rails' # installs RSpec gems with support for Rails
  gem 'factory_girl_rails' # creates test data
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara' # test web pages
  gem 'database_cleaner' # clean slate for db
  gem 'launchy' # view errors in browser
  gem 'selenium-webdriver' # for test that require js
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


# Custom added Gems
# ---- START ----

gem "administrate", github: "mariochavez/administrate", branch: "remove-inline_svg"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'mandrill-api'
gem 'annotate'

# Omniauth

gem 'omniauth-github'

# ---- END ----
```

Comment: I suggest you uninstall gem bcrypt at first, then rerun bundle install.

Comment: thanks. this helped. actually what has happened was I have installed few version of bcrypt and devise requires one version by i specified another.

Comment: most gems will depend on other specific version gems, bundle install will help you install these gems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please uninstall the `bcrypt` gem at first, then run `bundle install`.

Comment: glad to help you! 