# Rails Load Error - incompatible library version for bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bcrypt

My `rails s` and `rails c` has suddenly started refusing to boot up with the error below. I don't recall updating or deleting any gems. Any help in fixing the situation is greatly appreciated.

`incompatible library version - /Users/[me]/projects/[app]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle (LoadError)`

`bcrypt` is not an explicitly required gem in our project, but it's included in `Gemfile.lock` because it's a dependency: `bcrypt (3.1.12)`

So far I've tried these, but I get the same error:

1. Uninstalling and installing `bcrypt` in my system (according to this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099301/11249670))

```
gem uninstall bcrypt -v 3.1.12

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        bcrypt-3.1.12

sorcery-0.14.0 depends on bcrypt (~> 3.1)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled bcrypt-3.1.12
```

```
gem install bcrypt -v 3.1.12
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.12
```

2. `gem pristine --all`

Here are the results of what I get if I check the gem versions:

1. `gem info bcrypt`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bcrypt (3.1.12)
    Author: Coda Hale
    Homepage: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /Users/[me]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2

    OpenBSD's bcrypt() password hashing algorithm.
```

2. `bundle info bcrypt`

```
* bcrypt (3.1.12)
        Summary: OpenBSD's bcrypt() password hashing algorithm.
        Homepage: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby
        Path: /Users/[me]/projects/[app]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12
```

Comment: Did you try this one solutions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098432/unable-to-load-application-incompatible-library-version?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the question I linked
> Uninstalling and installing bcrypt in my system (according to this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099301/11249670))

Comment: Not install bcrypt manually after uninstalling just do, bundle install

Comment: Do you mean 1. `gem uninstall bcrypt`, then 2. `bundle install`? Tried that as well, same results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[RESOLVED]**

**[Solution 1]** I needed to uninstall/reinstall the gem in the `vendor/bundle` folder, instead of doing `gem uninstall` and `gem install`.

Here were the steps involved:

1. Check where your gem is saved using `otool -L` (mine was saved here: `[project root]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.12/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle`)
2. Remove everything in the `bcrypt-3.1.12` folder with `rm -rf`.
3. `bundle install --force --path vendor/bundle` to reinstall the `bcrypt-3.1.12` gem.

**[Solution 2]** What I ultimately ended up doing was to update `bcrypt`'s version with `bundle update bcrypt`. Guessing this update installed the gem cleanly in `vendor/bundle`, because all my `rails` commands started working again.

```
bundle update bcrypt
Using bcrypt 3.1.13 (was 3.1.12)
```

Hope these tips help anyone who runs into this in the future!

Comment: solution 1 works for me in rails 6. thanks!